# Defining function with different placeholders

Tags: python

New to python and my first time using stack so forgive me for any obvious errors. I am trying to define a function and can't seem to get the output I want.. ( "Hi, Corey" ) unless I define the function with empty placeholders. Literally started coding last week so I would appreciate if somebody told me in the most simple terms why this is the case.

```
def hello_func(greet="Hey", name="You"):
    return "{greet},{name}".format(greet, name)

print(hello_func("Hi","Corey"))
```

This was my original code which didn't produce the output I wanted.

```
def hello_func(greet="Hey", name="You"):
    return "{},{}".format(greet, name)

print(hello_func("Hi","Corey"))
```

While this code did produce the output.

Comment: Please read about placeholders here: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_format.asp

Comment: This is a good example of print formatting. https://pyformat.info/. It will help you understand

Answer (score 1):

You can write the function you want like:

```
def hello_func(greet="Hey", name="You"):
    return f"{greet},{name}"
```

Or if you want your first code to work, it should be something like:

```
def hello_func(greet="Hey", name="You"):
    return "{greet},{name}".format(greet=greet, name=name)
```

Since this requires a bit more to type, `f"..{A}.."` and `"..{}..".format(A)` are more commonly used.